# HTML input date - Data populated From DB

Tags: java, html, date, jsp

I am working on a webapp using jsp and servlets and I want to populate a date to HTML field which has the input type "Date".

I am pretty sure that my java code is getting the value for the input field and when I checked the value from "Inspect element" in browser, it shows that the value as expected. But the values are not visible in the field itself.

[image]

This is my jsp page's related field.

```
<input type="date" id="FeeStartDate" name="FeeStartDate" value = "'<%=Validation.formatDateForDateField(User.getFeeEndDate()) %>'">
```

As per below picture, value is there but it is not shown in the field. Why is that ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Ps : I have tried like this as well but same result.

<input type="date" id="FeeStartDate" name="FeeStartDate" value = **'<%=Validation.formatDateForDateField(User.getFeeEndDate()) %>'**>

If needed, this is the java method.

```
public static String formatDateForDateField(Date dDate)
{
    System.out.println("dDate 1 ==========> " + dDate);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    System.out.println("dDate 2 ==========> " + sdf.format(dDate));
    return sdf.format(dDate);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, there is `''` single quotes remove that .Also , try with `yyyy-mm-dd` format .

Answer (score 1):

Go Through this once:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Try This:

```
String date="2018-08-21"; //Format the date in this format

Date: <input type="date" name="date" value="<%=date%>">     //Using Expression tag

Date: <input type="date" name="date" value="2018-08-21">  // Plain value
```